# how to pass my input values to jsp using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

i am trying to pass data to insertUpdateDelete.jsp from test.jsp using angularjs. But no success.Here is my code
test.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/app.js">
</script>
<body ng-app="app">
<div id="divCtrl" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-include src="'images/3-epayindia product.png'"></div>
<input type="text" name="empCode" ng-model="empCode" value="" /> 
<input type="text" name="empName"  ng-model="empName" value="" /><br/> 
<input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addData()" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="updateData()" />

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

insertUpdateDelete.jsp

```
<html>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %>

<% 
String dml_type = request.getParameter("dml_type");
out.print(dml_type);
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/epay", "root", "root");
String emp_code = request.getParameter("empCode");
String emp_name = request.getParameter("empName");
String sql="";
if("Ins".equals(dml_type))
  sql = "insert into emp values(" + emp_code + ",'" + emp_name + "')";
else if("Del".equals(dml_type))
  sql = "delete from emp where emp_code = " + emp_code + " and emp_name = '" + emp_name + "'";
else if("Upd".equals(dml_type))
  sql = "update emp set emp_name = '" + emp_name + "' where emp_code = " + emp_code;
out.println(dml_type);    
try
{
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
 stmt.executeQuery(sql);
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
 out.print("SQL Error encountered " + dml_type  + "," + e.getMessage());
}
con.close();
con=null;
%>
</html>
```

app.js

```
app = angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$http) {
/*     This function is called from ng-click in button "Add"  which adds data in table EMP and updates the view */
     $scope.addData = function() {
       $http.post("http://localhost:8093/Angular/insertUpdateDelete.jsp?empCode=" + $scope.empCode + "&empName=" + 
         $scope.empName + "&dmlType=Ins")
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log('inserted successfully');

        });
/* dmlType checks the type of DML transaction to perform, this prevents from creating separate JSP files for insert, update and delete */
      }



/*     This function is called from ng-click in button "Update"  which updates data in table EMP and updates the view */     
       $scope.updateData = function() {
       $http.post("insertUpdateDelete.jsp?empCode=" + $scope.empCode + "&empName=" + 
       $scope.empName + "&dmlType=Upd")
        .success(function(response) {

        });     }



/*     This function is called from the link Remove in the third column of HTML table  which adds data in table EMP and updates the view */
     $scope.deleteData = function(curData) {
        $http.post("insertUpdateDelete.jsp?empCode=" + curData.EMP_CODE + 
         "&empName=" + curData.EMP_NAME + "&dmlType=Del")
        .success(function(response) {
               $scope.empData.splice($scope.empData.indexOf(curData),1);
        });     }


/*     This function gets fresh data from table  and updates the view */
/* get_oracle_data.jsp is explained in Oracle 12c data generator in JSON by dynamic sql using JSP */

  });
```

Please help to pass my data to insertUpdateDelete.jsp

Comment: what is the problem? what error are you getting?

Comment: i didn't get values in the insertUpdateDelete jsp. someone told retrieving method was wrong what can i do please help me